# Site only lets me vote 38 times, not enough for Vox Populi

Tags: bug

I tried to win this badge, but the site I am on ([Salesforce Stackexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)) will only let me vote 38 times in a day. So I can never achieve the required 40.

I have tried to vote 40 times last week as well, but got stuck at 38, the site would not let me vote anymore. I thought, maybe I have done something wrong or maybe other actions count as a vote as well.

So today I tried once more. I only voted, nothing else. Still, with 33 votes given, the site warns me that I have only 5 votes left.

It is starting to smell like a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212), the most likely explanation is that you only voted on 8 questions. That would cap you at 38 votes for the day instead of 40.

> The exact number of votes available [depends on your voting behavior for the day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/). You get a total of 40 votes per day, which are broken down into 10 "Q-votes" and 30 "QA-votes" per day.

There seems to be some more complexity to it than that, as [linked to further in the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279724). Weighting your votes towards questions earlier in the day, in particular, seems important to being able to hit the 40 vote cap.

Comment: There's a lot of linked reading you can pore over to better understand. Not knowing your exact voting behavior, I can only guess. That said, I added the `[status-review]` tag, which should draw some attention from folks who may be able to answer more authoritatively.

Comment: I guess you are right, I never knew this was so complicated. The description of Vox Populi is quite simple: "Use the maximum 40 votes in a day". The Electorate badge states that 25% of votes should be on questions. For my next attempt I will monitor my votes even more closely. I think Vox Populi should be changed to "Use the maximum number of votes in a day" (which doesn't require you to change voting behavior) or rephrased with the required percentage of question votes.